# Give pantheon terminal a fixed window name

Tags: release-loki, pantheon-terminal

I am using Elementary OS version 0.4.1.
I need to give pantheon terminal a fixed window name. Currently it is set to *mix* of command it is executing and the `pwd`, which is not what I want.
Is there a way to this? Note: I am using `zsh` shell
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just edit your bash.rc. This line
https://gist.github.com/kossoy/f87acbdc5b14e06bb20a2da645666637#file-bashrc-sh-L119

Comment: that line does not work in zsh. (I forgot to mention I use zsh shell, my apologies)